# about rpm module in python

Tags: python, rpm

I looked for some informations,the rpm module can only use for search installed rpm  package Information.I want to use the python rpm module to search *.rpm files in the folder and know their information,like release or version.Is this possible using the rpm module?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `yum` is all written in Python, so you may want to check that out. I think there are Python RPM libraries installed by default with it (on a Windows box right now, sorry).

Answer (score 6):

In case someone still ends up here while searching for an answer, here is how you can do it with python-rpm:

```
import os
import rpm

fdno = os.open(PATH_TO_RPM_FILE, os.O_RDONLY)
ts = rpm.ts()
hdr = ts.hdrFromFdno(fdno)
os.close(fdno)
```

(Note the call to os.close())

Now `hdr` holds the RPM header information. You can access individual attributes in dict style using RPMTAG_* values as keys, for example:

```
arch = hdr[rpm.RPMTAG_ARCH]
```

You can try reverse engineering all possible RPMTAG_* values using `dir()`:

```
import rpm
print '\n'.join(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('RPMTAG'), dir(rpm)))
```

You can also call `keys()` on `hdr`, but it will return the possible keys as integers, which might not be as friendly.

I have found that using python-rpm instead of invoking the command line tool as a subprocess gives a significant performance boost when a large number of RPM files are to be handled.

For further information, see http://rpm5.org/docs/api/classRpmhdr.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this that I know of. Your easiest bet is to make a call directly to the rpm command and parse the data

```
subprocess.check_output( ["rpm", "-qip", "CentOS_Image/Packages/python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.x86_64.rpm" ] )

'Name        : python\nVersion     : 2.6.6\nRelease     : 29.el6_2.2\nArchitecture: x86_64\nInstall Date: (not installed)\nGroup       : Development/Languages\nSize        : 21290059\nLicense     : Python\nSignature   : RSA/SHA1, Mon 18 Jun 2012 14:47:20 BST, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de\nSource RPM  : python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.src.rpm\nBuild Date  : Mon 18 Jun 2012 14:21:55 BST\nBuild Host  : c6b5.bsys.dev.centos.org\nRelocations : (not relocatable)\nPackager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>\nVendor      : CentOS\nURL         : http://www.python.org/\nSummary     : An interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language\nDescription :\nPython is an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming\nlanguage often compared to Tcl, Perl, Scheme or Java. Python includes\nmodules, classes, exceptions, very high level dynamic data types and\ndynamic typing. Python supports interfaces to many system calls and\nlibraries, as well as to various windowing systems (X11, Motif, Tk,\nMac and MFC).\n\nProgrammers can write new built-in modules for Python in C or C++.\nPython can be used as an extension language for applications that need\na programmable interface. This package contains most of the standard\nPython modules, as well as modules for interfacing to the Tix widget\nset for Tk and RPM.\n\nNote that documentation for Python is provided in the python-docs\npackage.\n'
```

Comment: You will want to look into `query-format` to make it easier to parse.